# The parameter is incorrect while rsa.Decrypt

Tags: encryption, rsa

getting an error "The parameter is incorrect" while using rsa.Decrypt method the public/private key is same while encrypt/decrypt. can someone help me where I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```cs
private const string Key = @"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";
        
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pwd = "ABC1564";
    string encrypt = Encrypt(pwd);
    string decrypt = Decrypt(encrypt);

    Console.WriteLine("Password  String :- " + pwd.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted String :- " + encrypt.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted String :- " + decrypt.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string Encrypt(string data)
{
    CspParameters CSPParam = new CspParameters();
    CSPParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(CSPParam);
    rsa.FromXmlString(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(Key)));
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt((new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(data), false));
}

private static string Decrypt(string Crypt)
{
    // Crypt Provider
    CspParameters CSPParam = new CspParameters();
    CSPParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(CSPParam);

    // Crypt Params
    string k = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(Key));
    rsa.FromXmlString(k);

    // Decrypt
    byte[] bi = (new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(Crypt)));
    byte[] bdecr = rsa.Decrypt(bi, false);

    // Return results
    return (new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()).GetString(bdecr);
}
```

Comment: During decryption you perform a decoding and encoding of the ciphertext with UTF-16LE, which corrupts the data. Instead use directly the base64 decoded ciphertext: `byte[] bi = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Crypt);`. Then decryption works.

Comment: Yes, that worked !. But while encrypt also I've used same (UTF-16LE). rsa.FromXmlString(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(Key)));  but Id did no fail while encryption.    anyway Thanks!

Comment: `System.Convert.FromBase64String(Key)` gives the UTF16-LE encoded xml of the key (check this e.g. [here](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex)), which therefore can be UTF-16LE decoded. In contrast, the ciphertext is not UTF-16LE (or more generally UTF-x) compatible and is therefore corrupted during UTF-16LE decoding/encoding.

Comment: Did anyone fixed this, I know the issue but don't know how to fix it. The issue is keys are generated in different machine. If keys are generated in the same machine it works.